# How to get integers from an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have an array of arrays. It's a map for a game. The ones represent walls.

```
var walls = []
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
walls.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I want to detect if the player has hit one of the walls.

Then I need to get the x and y location as integers.

I want to do something like:

```
if (playerX == walls[i] && if playerY == walls[i][j]){
  playerDead();
}
```

I want to compare playerX to the row and playerY to the column. But the row is an array and the column is an integer. How do I turn the row into an integer?

/Jens

Comment: what exactly row should represent as a number? can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your player location variables as indexes into the arrays:

```
if (walls[playerX][playerY] == 1){
  playerDead();
}
```

Comment: I feel  like there's a moderate chance that we're gonna want to reverse Y and X here, but that depends on OPs setup

Comment: Thank you! Didn't thought of that! But I get an error. "TypeError: walls[playerX] is undefined."

Comment: @Jens, then your `playerX` value is out of range (< 0 or > your map size) or you need to swap `PlayerX` and `PlayerY`.

Comment: I solved it. The playerX was multiplied by 20, since the grid is 20x20 on a 400x400 canvas. It works now!

Answer (score 1):

If playerX and playerY represent the x,y coordinates respectively then:

```
if(walls[playerX][playerY]){
    playerDead()
}
```

will run is player location corresponds to a wall.